# Flutter Notification not showing pop up

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Notifications I send with Firebase when the app is open, in the background, and closed work fine.

[image]

But I want to pop up, like this:
[image]

My codes;

**local_notification_service.dart:**

```
class LocalNotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize(BuildContext context) {
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/launcher_icon"),
            iOS: IOSInitializationSettings(
              requestSoundPermission: false,
              requestBadgePermission: false,
              requestAlertPermission: false,
            ));

    _notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (String? route) async {
      if (route != null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(route);
      }
    });
  }

  static void display(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;

      final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        "kasifkocaeli",
        "kasifkocaeli channel",
        channelDescription: "kasifkocaeli guzel",
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
      ));

      await _notificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body,
        notificationDetails,
        payload: message.data["route"],
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

**main.dart:**

```
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async{
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification!.title);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**choose_screen.dart:**

```
class _ChoosePageState extends State<ChoosePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    LocalNotificationService.initialize(context);

    //Bildirime tıklandığında gösterilecek mesaj
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      if (message != null) {
        final routeFromMessage = message.data["route"];

        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeFromMessage);
      }
    });

    //forground (uygulama önplandayken)
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      if (message.notification != null) {
        print(message.notification!.body);
        print(message.notification!.title);
      }

      LocalNotificationService.display(message);
    });

    //Uygulama arkaplandayken ve kullanıcı tıkladığında
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      final routeFromMessage = message.data["route"];

      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeFromMessage);
    });
  }
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
firebase_messaging: ^11.2.13
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.4.0
firebase_core: ^1.13.1
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.10
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
android:value="notification_app"/>
```

And this is my watched video (he did the same with me but the notification screen opens on his app, but not for me. [The scene where the notification is shown](https://youtu.be/p7aIZ3aEi2w?t=4205)

Comment: I'm facing the same problem ... but for me it's worst, because even in background it's not showing up but still appears in Notification Center .. how did you do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you ran the app before setting the Importance to Max, it may have been cached without that. I had the same issue and had to wipe the data of the Android emulator and run it again, and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open settings and select notifications, go to your app and select open channel name at the bottom of the screen then tick allow floating notifications

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can refer to this page -> https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-categories

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, my code was written correctly, all I had to do was run:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `flutter run`

to make it work.

Basically what @Ricky Kresslein said.